# Powershell - Grabbing Folder Names and Saving to Array Will Sometimes Grab Each Letter as an Item

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell

I am attempting to put together a .ps1 file to scan existing movies I have in my Plex storage and compare it to a drive I use to ingest movies. It will then make an array of movies I do not have (Determined by file name) and an array of movies I do already have. Before I go into more detail I will share how my movies are organized in my Plex Media Folder(s).

The root of my folder lists the type of media stored. For example:
\Tower.pauk.us\Movies, \Tv Shows, \Music, \Photos, etc.

For this program I am only focusing on the \Movies\ Folder.

Inside of the \Movies\ folder I have a folder for each letter of the alphabet and numbers and symbols. i.e. #\,\A\,\B\,...\Z\
Sometimes, within those folder I will have a folder for lets say, a "Quentin Tarantino Collection". Even though the movies within that folder don't start with "Q" the collection starts with "Q" so it will reside in the /Q/ folder.

Okay, so now that's over with I can start to try and explain what my existing code does. So here is my code:

```
$PlexMovieFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

$List1 = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
$List2 = @()
$Match = @()
$No_Match = @()


for ($i1 = 0; $i1 -le ($PlexMovieFolders.length - 1); $i1 += 1){
    $SubFolders = @()
    $folder = $PlexMovieFolders[$i1]
    $List2 += Get-ChildItem -path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
    $SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
    if ($SubFolders.Length -gt 0) {
            for($i2 = 0; $i2 -le ($SubFolders.Length - 1); $i2 += 1){
                $folder2 = $SubFolders[$i2]
                $List2 += Get-ChildItem -Path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\$folder2\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
    }
    }
}


for ($i2 = 0; $i2 -le ($List2.length - 1); $i2 += 1){
    Write-Host ($List2.length - $i2) "Items Left"
    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 -le ($List1.length - 1); $i1 += 1){
        if($List1[$i1] -eq $List2[$i2]){
            $Match += $List1[$i1]
        }else{
            $No_Match += $List1[$i1]
        }
    }
}
```

We will go line-by-line, obviously starting at the top.

```
$PlexMovieFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Here, the code will navigate to my Plex movie folder and save each folder name to an array called `$PlexMovieFolders`.

```
$List1 = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
```

Because the drive I use to ingest movies only has the files directly in the root all I do here is take each movie name and save it to an array called `$List1`.

```
$List2 = @()
$Match = @()
$No_Match = @()
```

This section sets a bunch of other variables used later in the script to arrays.

```
for ($i1 = 0; $i1 -le ($PlexMovieFolders.length - 1); $i1 += 1){
    $SubFolders = @()
    $folder = $PlexMovieFolders[$i1]
    $List2 += Get-ChildItem -path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
    $SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
    if ($SubFolders.Length -gt 0) {
            for($i2 = 0; $i2 -le ($SubFolders.Length - 1); $i2 += 1){
                $folder2 = $SubFolders[$i2]
                $List2 += Get-ChildItem -Path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\$folder2\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
    }
    }
}
```

This is a for loop. It will loop once for each item in the array `$PlexMovieFolders`. There is a lot going on in here so I will try to break this down a little...

```
$SubFolders = @()
```

Because sometimes I have sub folders within each letter I will need to have a variable that can have an array of each sub folder for every letter. I assume having this at the top of the for loop will clear the array every time the loop is ran.

```
$folder = $PlexMovieFolders[$i1]
```

This sets a variable to the single item in the `$PlexMovieFolders` array the loop happens to be on. I did this because using `$PlexMovieFolder[$i1]` within the actual command was giving me issues.

```
$List2 += Get-ChildItem -path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
```

This section will go through each and every letter folder in my \Movies\ folder of Plex. From there it will save every file name to an array excluding a few unnecessary files.

```
$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

This will go into the letter folder and grab all folder names and save them to an array called `$SubFolders`. This gets cleared every time the loop runs because each letter folder has it's own sub folders. This section is the problem section. Because for some reason, only while running within this script it will grab seemingly random, but always the same, folders and store each individual letter of the folder name as separate items in the array.

For example:
It will save `Rambo Movies` just fine as the whole folder name.

But when it attempts to save the "Quentin Tarantino Collection" in the array it will save it like this:

```
Q
u
e
n
t
i
n

T
a
r
a
n
t
i
n
o

C
o
l
l
e
c
t
i
o
n
```

It's very frustrating because when I run: `$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\@\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}` In a powershell terminal it works fine... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. and this is why I'm hoping to get some feedback on this.

```
if ($SubFolders.Length -gt 0) {
            for($i2 = 0; $i2 -le ($SubFolders.Length - 1); $i2 += 1){
                $folder2 = $SubFolders[$i2]
                $List2 += Get-ChildItem -Path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\$folder2\ -Name -File -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg
    }
    }
```

This section will see if the length of the `$SubFolders` array is greater than 0 and if so, it will go into that subfolder and save each file name to an array called `$List2` this array isn't cleared every time the loop runs because I need the complete list of movies in the end.

```
for ($i2 = 0; $i2 -le ($List2.length - 1); $i2 += 1){
    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 -le ($List1.length - 1); $i1 += 1){
        if($List1[$i1] -eq $List2[$i2]){
            $Match += $List1[$i1]
        }else{
            $No_Match += $List1[$i1]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the last section so far... there is a little bit going on here. What we are looking at is a the 'comparator' It will go through each item in `$List2` and see if any item is `$List1` matches it. If there is a match save it in the `$Match` array for me to verify later. and if there is no match save it in the `$No_Match`. Later I will use this `$No_Match` array to automatically copy those movies over to the plex Movie folder.

TLDR;
`$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\$folder\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}`
Will sometimes grab the folder name characters rather than the folder name.
For Example:

```
Q
u
e
n
t
i
n

T
a
r
a
n
t
i
n
o

C
o
l
l
e
c
t
i
o
n
```

But his command will run just fine if I type out the variables by hand.
For Example:
`$SubFolders = Get-ChildItem \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies\Q\ | Where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}`
Will save as `Quentin Tarantino Collection`

UPDATE (Dec. 30th, 2019):

Due to some in-site from Keith Miller, I was able to reduce the total amount of code by about half.

I'm not using this to collect the file information. I've also added TV Shows.

```
$NewMovieDir = 'F:\'
$NewShowDir = 'D:\TV'


$Movies_New = (Get-ChildItem -Path $NewMovieDir -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name
$Movies_Old = (Get-ChildItem -Path \\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Movies -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name
$Shows_New = (Get-ChildItem -Path $NewShowDir -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name
$Shows_Old = (Get-ChildItem -Path '\\Tower.pauk.us\Plex\Tv Shows' -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name
```

UPDATE (Jan. 4th, 2020):

I've ran into an issue. Some of the movies in my ingesting drive are not formatted the same way the movies in my Plex folder are formatted. For Example. I try to keep my naming scheme as `Title (year).xyz` (Elf (2003).mp4).
Sometimes the movies in my ingest drive don't look like `Title (year).xyz` but instead they are `Title.xyz`. So when I'm trying to compare these items I'm getting a lot of false mismatches. To combat this I've decided to try to strip everything after the title and go without the year completely. My code is as follows: `(Get-ChildItem -Path $NewMovieDir -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\([^\)]+\)'} | ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd()}` This does a great job in removing the (YYYY) but does a terrible job at removing the trailing spaces. Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing that, but it seems to me you're doing a lot of unnecessary work if the goal is simply two lists: movies that are in both locations and those missing from F:|\

Comment: If the path doesn't matter, something like the following should get all your Plex movie names: `$List1 = (Get-ChildItem -Path F:\ -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name
`

Comment: Then, take a look at the help for [Compare-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6). With the various parameters, it can generate both of your lists.

Comment: I should've mentioned, I'm new to powershell, so I'm sure there is a lot of unnecessary code.. I'll research into that link. Tank you!

Comment: Great. You can append updates to your original post with progress. Keep us posted.

Comment: Looking good! How's the comparison going?

Comment: It's been a while since I've played with it. But I'm stuck.. Allow me to explain...

I've been trying to keep my movie naming consistent. I try to do Movie Title (YYYY).xyz. (i.e.  Elf (2003).mp4) with this ingest drive, the movie names are not consistent. Some may have the year some may not. So I've added something to remove (YYYY) from each movie name:
`(Get-ChildItem -Path $NewMovieDir -File -Recurse -Exclude *.srt,*.DS_Store,*.dat,*.jpg).Name | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\([^\)]+\)'}`
But then I'm left with a space at the end of the object.

Comment: So I tried adding `| ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd()}` but that does not seem to remove any trailing spaces.

Comment: `TrimEnd()` isn't working because the space is not at the end of the string, the file extension is! Maybe manipulate the basename and then append the extension.

Comment: I didn't event think about the extension being a factor... I'll have to get rid of the extension too. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the extension, use `(Get-ChildItem...).BaseName`.